# Nutch: how to exclude non-English pages?

Tags: indexing, nutch

I was wondering if there is a simple mechanism to exclude pages that are non-English from the indexing process? For example, the dmoz seed urls list contains wikipedia pages in many languages and they are the prime candidates for exclusion.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any url pattern that is followed by all English pages?
eg. Wikipedia has "`en`" in the url for english like

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_books

. For other language, it does NOT has `en` in the url like

> http://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:Wikipedia:Libros

If you can define that, then it will be easily done by adding regex rule in the $NUTCH_CONF_DIR/regex-urlfilter.txt file so include pages which have the pattern for english and discard the other ones.

Comment: Thats the problem. The language is based on the content, not on the url. Probably have to write a plugin...